# Generate the Ocelot downstream paths for all endpoints using Swagger docs?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, gateway, ocelot

I don't know if what I'm asking is possible. But I have several APIs with about 100 endpoints in total. We are configuring the APIs to use Ocelot Gateway and I was wondering if there's an efficient way to generate the ocelot.json downstream settings. Since we already have the swagger docs generated, is there a library/package which we can use to generate the downstream URLs using the swagger docs?

Answer (score 0):

[MMLib SwaggerForOcelot](https://github.com/Burgyn/MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot) extension provides a better way to literally document your downstream endpoints. They use a key to identify the APIs within the ocelot files. You can also refer to this [article](https://blog.burgyn.online/2020/04/17/swagger-for-ocelot-api-gateway-en).

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the routes for all the endpoints with the Swagger page.

1. Run your project, let it open in the browser.
2. Open the developer mode (e.g., via inspect element).
3. Run the following in the console:

   ```
   var routes = [];
   //import jquery first.
   script = document.createElement('script');

   script.onload = function() {
       // jQuery is available now

       generateAllroutes();
   };

   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js?v=24';
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   head.appendChild(script);

   function generateAllroutes() {

       //expanding all nodes
       $('.opblock-tag.no-desc').trigger('click');

       function camelize(str) {
           return str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(word, index) {
               return index === 0 ? word.toLowerCase() : word.toUpperCase();
           }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
       }

       function capitalize(word) {
           return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
       }

       var listOpaths = $('.opblock-summary-path');

       for (var i = 0, len = listOpaths.length; i < len; i++) {
           var pp = $(listOpaths[i]);
           var path = pp.attr('data-path');
           var method = capitalize(pp.parent().find('.opblock-summary-method').text());
           routes.push({
               "DownstreamPathTemplate": path,
               "DownstreamScheme": "https",
               "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [{
                   "Host": "localhost",
                   "Port": 44338
               }],
               "UpstreamPathTemplate": path,
               "UpstreamHttpMethod": [method]
           });
       }


   }
   ```
4. Then the routes will be on the routes array.